# D3.JS about draw 3 chart in same page and some more thing

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I'm student, and i'm not good at english. i'm so sorry and worry about it...

anyway, I wanna draw 3 scatter plot chart in same page (and there is single data file(csv))

And Data Set is like this (Name, Height, Weight, Grade(0.0~5.0) )

----------------- Browse Chart.Html -------------------------

```
          Chart1
```

------------------------------ [Height]

```
          Chart2
```

------------------------------ [Weight]

```
          Chart3
```

------------------------------ [Grade]

---

I read some document about d3.js

use  to make 3 area in html file,  ... etc

Aren't there any alternatives?

and other question is

if data sets are

name, height, weight, grade
John, 180, 80, 4.5
Smith, 175,95, 3.2
Ryu, 187, 87, 4.0

there are 3 Dots on chart

if user click one dot in chart1, (if that dot means Ryu, 187, 87, 4.0)

dot color have to change(like default = red, but if clicked blue) on chart1, chart2, chart3

is it possible? if it is, please tell me example or document to useful,

if you need to more explantion, i will update more

:) Thank you for reading my question.

Answer (score 0):

Joony,

Here's a novice tutorial on creating a Scatter Plot.

[**Scatter Plot - Scott Murray**](http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/making-a-scatterplot).

You can directly load your data using d3.csv() function. More info over [**here**](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV).

Follow the instruction for the Scatter Plot chart and wrap all the codes inside d3.csv like this.

I'd suggest you to create 3 separate div for 3 charts and use the same codes for the scatter plot and just change the column name for the data that's going to be used for chart. Once you load the data using d3.csv store the 3 column names to 3 variables and that'll make you easy on creating the charts.

Before you start doing anything, please go through [**D3 Tips and Tricks by Lean Pub**](https://leanpub.com/D3-Tips-and-Tricks).

Free PDF for all the novice.

```
    d3.csv("path to the file.csv", function(data, error) {

    codes for your scatter plot

    })
```

More info on the d3 in this [**link**](http://d3js.org) with all the documentaion and examples.